# Building a angular JS web project

Tags: javascript, eclipse, angularjs, spring, spring-mvc

I am trying to build an angular js web project. The project will be such that, on UI side, I will have html with angular to handle presentation. Data on/from UI will be obtained/posted using ajax. 
These ajax calls will take us to one of the methods in spring controller. These method will connect to another Rest WS application to obtain data / save data.

I have been able to understand the Angular JS framework and I feel comfortable to an extent working on it now. However I have no experience in designing an application structure from scratch. I have read http://scotch.io/tutorials/javascript/angularjs-best-practices-directory-structure to understand the directory structure's best practices.
I have integrated angular with my eclipse IDE. 
Now, my question is, how should I go ahead with designing my application. Will it be the way we normally use js in a J2EE application? Or it is to be done in some other better/advisable way?

Any help is appreciated.
PS: Is it advisable to build an angular JS as static Web Project? I read this somewhere, I cant find the link now.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some tips:

1. Separate your javascript files and organize them so that they are functionally together.
2. Setup multiple SPAs if necessary, and organize your files/folders in the same way for each SPA:

   ```
      home\index.html
      home\index.js
      home\index-controller.js
      home\module.js // contains the Angular module definition
      home\templates\user-control1.html
      admin\index.html
      admin\index.js
      admin\index-controller.js
      admin\module.js
      admin\templates\user-control2.html
   ```
3. Create Angular UI modules specific to your application so that they can be re-used

   ```
    shared\your-ui.js // this angular module contains UI directives
    shared\your-ui\directives\table.js
    shared\your-ui\directives\table-controller.js
    shared\your-ui\directives\templates\user-control.html
    shared\your-ui\services\test-service.js
   ```
4. Use Grunt or Gulp to build your JS files, minify them, run automated tests, and deploy them to where they need to be.  Deploy your Angular UI modules and deploy your App.js module.
5. Use a javascript module loader (RequireJS, Webpack) so that dependent files can remain separate.

Comment: Thanks for the direction. Can you please enlighten me on the content of module.js? 
I cant think of anything else apart from code given below as the content (excuse my less knowledge of subject) :


    var phonecatApp = angular.module('phonecatApp', []);

definition of the controller should go to a phonecatAppController.js, correct me if I am wrong? So I dont understand why do we make a seperate file for module?

Comment: You are correct. A module is simply: var app = angular.module('app', ['your-ui']);, just separated out into a module.js file. If you use webpack or requirejs, you are able to separate your code like this - and you should.

Comment: Separate files are good practice, especially if it is a large scale project, with multiple team-members, and your source code is under source control (also a good practice).  Each file should have one reason to change, and with module.js, it's clear there can only be one reason (or a couple).